# Efficiently creating a database to analyze relationships between information

Tags: python, database-design, postgresql, psycopg2

So I am trying to take a large number of xml files (None are that big in particular and I can split them up as I see fit.) In all there is about 70GB worth of data. For the sake of reference the loading script is written in python and uses psycopg2 to interface with a postgres table.

Anyway, what I am trying to do is to deal with data that works something like this. The relation count being the number of time the two tags are seen together and the tag count being the number of time the tag has been seen. I have all the tags already its just getting the times they appear and the times they appear together of the xml that has become a problem.

```
         Tag Table                |              Relations Table
```

```
 TagID      TagName   TagCount    |         tag1       tag2    relationCount
```

```
   1         Dogs        20       |          1           2            5
```

```
   2         Beagles     10       |          1           3            2
```

```
   3         Birds       11       |          2           3            7
```

The problem I am encountering is getting the data to load in a reasonable amount of time. I have been iterating over the update methods as I count how often the tags come up in the xml files.

I suppose I am asking if anyone has any ideas. Should I create some sort of buffer to hold the update info and try to use cur.executeall() periodically and/or should I restructure the database somehow. Anyway, any and all thoughts on this issue are appreciated.

Comment: @user497451 - I guess you are doing the counting on Python so you will only have as many inserts/updates as those found in Python. Is it? Each XML file processed resets the previous count or does it adds to the previous?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this "...I have been iterating over the update methods" it sounds like you are updating the database rows as you go?  If this is so, consider writing some code that passes the XML, accumulates the totals you are tracking, outputs them to a file, and then loads that file with COPY.

If you are updating existing data, try something like this:

1) Pass the XML file(s) to generate all new totals from the new data

2) COPY that into a working table - a table that you clear out before and after every batch

3) Issue an INSERT from the working table to the real tables for all rows that cannot be found, inserting zeros for all values

4) Issue an UPDATE from the working table to the real tables to increment the counters.

5) Truncate the working table.

Comment: +1 for recommending a cheap, fast, scalable AND simple approach that can be achieved with minimal code and effort.

Comment: And everything except the 'truncate' can be done in a transaction, which ought to be more efficient.

Comment: Truncate can be inside a transaction too. Arguably you should truncate at the start and end of the transaction, or just use a temp table with "on commit drop" or "on commit delete rows"

Comment: Actually putting all of into a transaction is not efficient because it forces te server to manage far more resources.  Steps 3 and 4 belong in separate transactions

Comment: That would mesh ideally with a temp table configured to forget its content at the end of each transaction. Although I'm not sure precisely which extra resources you're so worried about here?

Comment: Mutli-row transactions require locks = RAM, and the proper tracking of intermediate values, which in Postgres is MVCC.  It is not a linear relationship, the resource requirements go way up as the number of rows goes up.  Keeping steps 3 and 4 in a transaction more than doubles the involved rows, and greatly more than doubles the RAM requirements.